# Set a title programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Here is my storyboard. My TabBarController references to the NavigationController (which has a own class) in the second picture.

I am not able to set a title via code. I tried every piece of code inside my **MapsViewController** & **MapsNavigationViewController** I found on Google & co.

viewController.title = "some title" <- not working

self.title = "some title" <- not working

navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title" <- not working

self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title" <- not working

self.parent?.title = "some title" <- not working

navigationItem.title = "What ever you want" <- not working

How can I set a title to my Navigation programmatically...?

1) [image]

2) [image]

3) [image]

Edit: View Hierachy:

[image]

Comment: have you checked that navigation bar is not hidden, when mapViewController is shown. self.title = "blablabla" should work debug your view herarchy to get a better idea

Comment: hi kjoe, self.title = "blablabla" will change the title of my tabbarcontroller item, but no effect on my navigationcontroller item. will try to debug it. edit: navigationbar is of course not hidden

Comment: but you got to do it in MapViewcontroller not in your tabBarController, that's why I suggest to debug the view herarchy since tittle is not shown maybe the navigation bar is hidden for some reason

Comment: EDIT: i have added the view hierachy EDITEND.  -  maybe a missunderstanding here. i wrote self.title = "bla" in my MapViewController, not in the tabbarcontroller and it changes the tabbaritem title.. i am trying to find how i can debug view hierachy.

Comment: have you a custom class for TabBarController and the NavigationController

Comment: what do you set as tittle I guess there is a title just in white color

Comment: Sir, I was in full retard mode. You are right. The tint color was white ........ shame on me.

Comment: no problem man, things that happens all days

Comment: Why don't you do the whole thing programmatically? Storyboard is not the future.

Comment: Because I am an beginner

Answer (score 1):

Solution: The title color should not be the same as the navigation bar color. Thanks to @kjoe.

Answer (score 1):

Insert navigation controller in between the view controller and tabbarController .Set viewcontrollers as rootviewcontroller from navigation controller.OR you can embed also. Then set in Perticular viewController class ViewDidLoad()

```
self.title = "some title"
```

OR

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below code will help you. I am always using it for set Navigation bar programatically.

```
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black          
    self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white , NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.init(name: "Poppins-SemiBold", size: 15)!]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false // its based on your requirement that your app's navigation bar should be transparent or not
```

You can use this code in viewWillAppear.

Just replace your application theme color and Title in above code.